# Change certain values inside an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to check(validate) all of the value's inside an array, and if they are not valid replace them with a new value.

I need to replace the non-numbers and empty value's with for example 0 or NULL.

```
$output = array(1, 345, 55, '', 09, 0, 543, 'hello', 5, 'world')
```

Comment: `array_map(function ($i) { return is_int($i) ? $i : null; }, $array)`

Comment: @deceze Oh, so floats aren't numbers? If one value is (e.g.) 4.5, it will be replaced with NULL even if it is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function replace($ao){
   if(is_numeric($ao)) return $ao;
   return NULL;
}

array_map("replace", $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array_filter($array, "is_numeric");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
function checkAR($output){
  $newar=array();
    foreach($output as $o){
     if(is_numeric($o)) $newar[]=$o;
    else $newar[]=0;
}

 return $newar;
}
```